# docker build error Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension for mimemagic-0.3.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, dockerfile, ruby-on-rails-5

I have to build a docker image on my local machine to verify whether it is a building an image or not but I am facing this issue while building the docker image on a local machine.

```
 Installing mime magic 0.3.9 with native extensions
    Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/bundle/gems/mimemagic-0.3.9/ext/mimemagic
/usr/local/bin/ruby -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems -rrubygems
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake
RUBYARCHDIR\=/usr/local/bundle/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/mimemagic-0.3.9
RUBYLIBDIR\=/usr/local/bundle/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/mimemagic-0.3.9
rake aborted!
Could not find MIME type database in the following locations:
["/usr/local/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml",
"/opt/homebrew/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml",
"/usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml"]


/usr/local/bundle/gems/mimemagic-0.3.9/ext/mimemagic/Rakefile:25:in `block in
<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => default
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

rake failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/bundle/gems/mimemagic-0.3.9 for
inspection.
Results logged to
/usr/local/bundle/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/mimemagic-0.3.9/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing mimemagic (0.3.9), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install mimemagic -v '0.3.9' --source
'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. Modify the `Dockerfile` to install the `shared-mime-info` package. E.g. on Debian-based images:

   `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y shared-mime-info`
2. If it still won't work, then you may need to update the `mimemagic` gem. On your host, update `mimemagic` in the Rails app's `Gemfile`/`Gemfile.lock`. You may need to install `shared-mime-info` first: If the host is macOS, you may need to run `brew install shared-mime-info`; if the host is Ubuntu, you may need to run `apt-get install shared-mime-info`. Then run

   `bundle update mimemagic`
3. If your `Dockerfile` downloads the Rails app from a repo, push your changes to that repo first. Or, for testing, modify the `Dockerfile` to copy in the Rails app from the host instead.

Answer (score 20):

If you are using macOS, try the following

```
 brew install shared-mime-info
 bundle update mimemagic
```

And the try to bundle your gem file